# How to partially read a CSV file with Super CSV

Tags: csv, supercsv

I have a csv file with 24 columns. Out of these I only want to read 3 columns. I see that super CSV is a very powerful library, but I can't figure out how to partially read a CSV. The link that have on [partial reading](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_partial_reading.html) is broken.

Please do help me out with a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** SourceForge is back online! The Super CSV site should work now :)

That's the correct link, but SourceForge project websites are down right now (according to the [SourceForge blog](https://sourceforge.net/blog/)):

> Starting at 12:59 UTC today, we experienced a site outage, causing
>   general connectivity issues sitewide. At 15:12 UTC, site connectivity
>   was restored and most services, including downloads, are now back
>   online. Some services are however are offline while we continue to
>   diagnose and determine the root cause for this issue. The services
>   still offline are:
>
> Project web (ie., projectname.sourceforge.net pages) and associated
>   shell and database services. This also includes access through sftp,
>   scp, and rsync via ssh.

So you have a few options:

- view the [source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/code/255/tree/trunk/super-csv/src/test/java/org/supercsv/example/Reading.java#l164) of the reading example on SourceForge (this part of SF is still working). There's a link to download the file at the top left.
- check out the project source from subversion (you can view/run the reading example listed above to see how it works, or you can even run `mvn site:site` to generate the project website locally
- view the [cached page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aAQEq6jpg5dsJ%3asupercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_partial_reading.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) from Google

I hope you enjoy using Super CSV - if you have any other questions feel free to post them here on SO, or on the [project help forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/discussion/718795/) on SourceForge.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now... Will share a blog based on some work I have done. Kudos on this neat library.